# Trying to FadeTransition an array of Text nodes one by one

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make the elements of a `Text` array fade away one by one in a `for` loop, but for some reason they fade away together.

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < citiesText.length; i++) {
    if (i != cityNum) {

        PauseTransition pause = new
        PauseTransition(Duration.millis(3000));
        FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), citiesText[i]);
        SequentialTransition st = new SequentialTransition(pause, ft);

        ft.setFromValue(1);
        ft.setToValue(0);
        st.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing you are doing but with Cards.

I got it to work by nesting `SequentialTransition`s.

I did something similar to this:

```
private SequentialTransition slideshow = new SequentialTransition();

for(int i = 0; i < citiesText.length; i++){
    SequentialTransition seq = new SequentialTransition();

    FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(2000), citiesText[i]);
    fade.setFromValue(1);
    fade.setToValue(0);
    PauseTransition stop = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(3000));

    seq.getChildren().addAll(fade, stop);
    slideshow.getChildren().add(seq);
}
slideshow.play();
```

As you can see I nested teh `SequentialTransition`s so that each `citiesText` has its own, but they play in order because of the outer `SequentialTransition`

Answer (score 0):

Your `PauseTransition` defines a pause of three seconds (btw [`Duration.seconds(3)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Duration.html#seconds-double-) would have been clearer). You create all Transitions with the same delay, and then you start them at once. Thus they all wait three seconds and then Fade for three seconds.

Note there is no need to create a `PauseTransition`, a `FadeTransition` and then combine them into a `SequentionalTransition`, the `Animation` superclass has a [`setDelay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setDelay-javafx.util.Duration-) which you can use to delay the execution of the animation.

The easiest change for your code would be to keep a delay counter and increment it each time:

```
double delay = 0d;

for (....) {
    if (....) {
        FadeTransition fade = ....;
        ....

        fade.setDelay(Duration.seconds(delay));
        delay += 3d;
        fade.play();
    }
}
```